# Data Trigger for a column's cell - Datagrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a simple datadtgrid with 3 columns. I would like to get a "data trigger" on `ColumnA` cells; if user selects any of the cells in `ColumnA`, then "get that value" and do something with it. Ultimately, I will use that cell value to populate another datagrid. But first, I just want to put a data trigger on the column and extract that information in the code behind.

Here is the XAML code:

I did put `<style.triggers>`on the column but no idea how to proceed further.

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ProducerReport1" ItemsSource="{Binding PopulateProducerData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                                    >

                                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnA" Binding="{Binding ProducerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True"  >

                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                                            <Style.Triggers>

                                                            </Style.Triggers>  
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>


                                                  </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnB" Binding="{Binding reservoirname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" >

    </DataGridTextColumn>
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnC" Binding="{Binding subsectorname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" >

 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `DataGridCell` by using a `CellStyle`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnA" Binding="{Binding ProducerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="dg_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

---

```
private void dg_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    dynamic dataObject = cell.DataContext;
    string producerName = dataObject.ProducerName;
    //do something...
}
```